# how to change scheduling policy in cloudsim?

Tags: cloudsim

I want to change the default scheduling policy of cloudsim which is FCFS. To update the default policy, i need to make changes in submitCloudlets() method of DatacenterBroker class or also need to update few other methods ??

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 0):

The point is where you want to schedule, at the cloudlets level[scheduling the cloudlets to the VMs] or at the Host level [Scheduling the VMs to the suitable hosts]

To schedule your policy at host level, you can either write your own VMallocationPolicy class and use it, or edit allocateHostForVm method in VMallocationPolicySimple class (the policy that's been used as a default in many examples).

For cloudlets also, you can define your own scheduler policy class and use it, or write your own method in datacenterBroker class that suits your needs.

It is always better to write a new method or a new class for your personal "experiments", as changing already written methods and classes may affect the performance of other relative examples provided within the cloudsim. This may lead to loss of track and makes it more difficult for future references.

Hope it helps.